# bash file globbing anomaly

Tags: bash, glob

The bash manual (I'm using version 4.3.42 on OSX) states that the vertical bar '|' character is used as a separator for multiple file patterns in file globbing. Thus, the following should work on my system:

```
projectFiles=./config/**/*|./support/**/*
```

However, the second pattern gives a "Permission denied" on the last file that is in that directory structure so the pattern is never resolved into projectFiles. I've tried variations on this, including wrapping the patterns in parentheses,

```
projectFiles=(./config/**/*)|(./support/**/*)
```

which is laid out in the manual, but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you link the relevant portion of the manual?  In shell scripting `|` is for piping between programs.  Your "permission denied" error is from trying to execute whatever `./support/**/*` resolves to.

Comment: Also, globbing isn't performed *at all* during a simple assignment; try `foo=*`, then compare `echo "$foo"` with `echo $foo`. Globbing does occur during *array* assignment; see `foo=(*)`; echo "${foo[@]}"`.

Comment: Note that you can do this without extglob, `./{config,support}/**/*`, which would just expand to the path with config and the path with support space delimited and then do pattern matching. Or `./@(config|support)/**/*` with extglob. Either of which seems cleaner.

Comment: @janos It doesn't really answer the question alone, but you can add it to yours if you want. `chepner's` point is also probably worth mentioning.

Comment: @BroSlow done and done, thanks for letting me use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably referring to this part in [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

> ```
>    If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
>    extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the  following
>    description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
>    by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol-
>    lowing sub-patterns:
>
>           ?(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>           *(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
>           !(pattern-list)
>                  Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

The `|` separator works in pattern-lists as explained, but only when `extglob` is enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Try this:

```
projectFiles=*(./config/**/*|./support/**/*)
```

As [@BroSlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) pointed out in a comment:

> Note that you can do this without `extglob`, `./{config,support}/**/*`, which would just expand to the path with config and the path with support space delimited and then do pattern matching. Or `./@(config|support)/**/*` with `extglob`. Either of which seems cleaner.

[@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s comment is also worth mentioning:

> Also, globbing isn't performed at all during a simple assignment; try `foo=*`, then compare `echo "$foo"` with `echo $foo`. Globbing does occur during array assignment; see `foo=(*); echo "${foo[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks, @janos...couple of things:
1) projectFiles=*(./config/**/*|./support/**/*) didn't work; all I get is "No such file or directory" when running `ls $projectFiles`
2) echo $foo does the file globbing while echo "$foo" returns '*' - nice example to point out the difference

Comment: And yes... that was the section in man bash that caught my attention

Comment: And... your other two options -- ./{config,support}/**/* and ./@(config|support)/**/* -- both work. Thanks to you and BroSlow and chepner for the combined answer!